# Does anyone have any useful resources to share or tips to offer for developing a MUD?

Tags: mud

As a hobby project I am trying to create a ROM (Diku-Merc based) derivative. (Now defunct) I would appreciate it if anybody has done something similar and has some useful resources to share or tips to offer. I'm finding that a lot the resources such as mailing lists are no longer active and many links are dead.

I've picked ROM because that is what I am familiar as a player, but the source is more complicated than anything I have come across and I wouldn't mind picking a code base that was easier to understand. Any recommendations before I dive in in earnest would also be appreciated.

As for mudding communities in general I don't know of much beyond the [mud connector](http://www.mudconnect.com/) because I've always been in more of a user/player role than developer. A forgiving and active place where I can get answers to my questions is what I value most.

Comment: Sorry, I know the question wasn't very specific (still isn't) but this is new enough for me that I don't even know what I should be looking out for. In hindsight I probably should have asked this on a mud forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After extensive research I've decided to go with a  [tba](http://www.tbamud.com/) code base. I may elaborate later but very broadly

- Coding experience is more important than experience as a player and this has convinced me to abandon my roots. I wanted a well documented, reasonably modern, managable code base undergoing active development and this seems to fit the bill.

Anyways muds are truly a labour of love and you have to have a few screws loose if you plan to run one. Moreover the glory days have passed (it seems like there many muds shut down en masse around 2000) and in my opinion the community is largely inactive and fragmented. An exerpt from from some of the tba docs sums this up nicely:

> So, you're sure you want to run your own MUD? If you're already an
>   old hand at playing MUDs and you've
>   decided you want to start one of your
>   own, here is our advice: sleep on it,
>   try several other MUDs first. Work
>   your way up to an admin position and
>   see what running a MUD is really
>   about. It is not all fun and games.
>   You actually have to deal with people,
>   you have to babysit the players, and
>   be constantly nagged about things you
>   need to do or change. Running a MUD is
>   extremely time consuming if you do it
>   well, if you are not going to do it
>   well then don't bother. Just playing
>   MUDs is masochistic enough, isn't
>   it? Or are you trying to shave that
>   extra point off your GPA, jump down
>   that one last notch on your next job
>   evaluation, or get rid of that pesky
>   Significant Other for good? If you
>   think silly distractions like having
>   friends and seeing daylight are
>   preventing you from realizing your
>   full potential in the MUD world, being
>   a MUD Administrator is the job for
>   you.

Anyways I don't have any high hopes for success, but this is something I will find interesting, improve my code-fu and will keep me busy for many years to come :D

Comment: This will definitely hit on a lot of different aspects in software development, except the whole UI part.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

There is no active ROM developer mailing list, so tba definitely is a better choice. There was some effort to clean up ROM with the RaM project.

Dead Souls sees active development as well (the main dev is a hero in my eyes for the amount of work he produces).

I would not recommend MUCK as the userbase is rather small. However that is not to say there isn't good work being done -- look up the user Valente on the code subforum of the wora.netlosers.com forum, as he's probably one of the foremost MUCK developers at the moment.

However if you thought that ROM was complicated I should caution you about tackling an established/canon codebase for any purpose other than getting a familiarity with mud servers. For actual development you may be better off with a barebones codebase such as NakedMUD (C/Python) or even something slimmer than that such as Socketmud (ports in many languages).

There are of course dozens of mud servers you can look at; all will be educational in some manner, but in the beginning stages it won't be obvious what is good practice and what is not. You may want to look up ColdC (similar to LP) and TeensyMUD (Ruby) to study. The author of Teensy, Jon Lambert, has a useful developer site up at http://sourcery.dyndns.org/.

However you'll find very experienced ROM and tba (i.e., Circle) developers at MudBytes, and I'll second Sam to say that is the most active mud developer site currently. It's a little surprising but in the last year there has been a significant growth in activity at MB. I think people are coming in from the fold so to speak and gathering at MB. There also is a good-sized code repository at MB as well.

Your other options are The Mudconnector which you already know, Top Mud Sites which has a somewhat smaller crowd of mostly developers (typically of established and long-running muds), and Mudlab, which is much quieter but usually with a good signal to noise ratio. MudGamers is an interesting new site with a fairly quiet forum, but a new approach to creating a more contemporary-looking portal for playing muds.

Not to be overlooked is the archive for the old mud-dev mailing list. There is a staggering amount of information to be gleaned there. The raw archive can be found at muddev.wishes.net/. Richard Tew also has done some noble work in combing through old usenet archives to find valuable mud development related threads, which you can find through his mud tag at posted-stuff.blogspot.com/search/label/mud.

I should note that many muds use the IMC chat network to link muds (MB has a portal to this as well on the front page of their site). Once your mud is running it can be useful to get on IMC if you're in need of real-time chat to fix a problem (of course, there are many IMC channels and you'll want to choose which one you use prudently).

Despite the fact that muds today are niche at best and unheard of at worst, there is no shortage of new muds in development. They offer a design and programming challenge that is still accessible to the solo developer, unlike any graphical game of equal size or complexity.

Furthermore you shouldn't be discouraged if it feels like you'll never release a playable game. Like many larger projects you may start and abandon it many times over, but you'll be building proficiencies across a wide spectrum of programming skillsets and applications -- not many projects will allow you to take such a whole systems approach. Good luck!

Comment: Note that Richard Tew recently collated a new copy of the mud-dev archive in a mbox archive, also available for download: 

http://www.disinterest.org/resource/MUD-Dev

If you prefer that to the forum-version archive.

Answer (score 3):

An active community seems to be around for the Dead Souls MUDlib

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Souls_MUDlib

I was an old player of Nightmare LPMud which sadly disappeared.  I'm not much in for the coding of these MUDs, but I have been following this community loosely just due to so many positive MUDding memories.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Nameless MUCK](http://nmc.limitless.org/). It's a solid piece of software.

Answer (score 2):

First concentrate on getting or finding a solid Telnet Socket library going, this is generally the main protocol for a MUD.

Next, create a FULL list of features that you want to implement, you should probably get some sort of feature or bug tracking system setup (even if it is a spreadsheet). Then prioritize the features based on dependencies of other systems.

Check out http://www.gamasutra.com for some architectural discussions on creating games in general, creating basic AI, character systems, and multi-player games.

Once you understand the theory, it is just a butt load of programming to build in everything you want to support.

Comment: btw, i got my start in programming with DikuMud a while back, its a great learning experience as it touches on a lot of the fundamentals of programming.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make the MUD engine abstract enough to run behind both a terminal client, a web-based Ajax client, and maybe stand-alone clients - i.e., don't tie the front end in with the actual game logic. I'm not averse to a MUD actually using a decent font for the text, and real graphics (as interstitials or to make notes on the bulletin board look like notes, etc), not in place of the text based interface) where necessary instead of ASCII, etc.

You might also want to have some MUD script file converters into your own format, so that you don't have to spend ages creating zones.

I find the problem with MUDs is that there is too much emphasis on killing NPCs, and not many puzzles or other interesting aspects. So a more interesting, story-oriented (possibly to the extend of sharding zones for single-player or single-team use) engine could be a nice feature to have.

Answer (score 2):

I will take this opportunity to recommend [MudBytes](http://www.mudbytes.net), which is probably the most active MUD developer site available right now.